# Unable to find an Audio Interface attached to the first HD card. Please check power and digilink cables. Click OK to rescan

Tags: troubleshooting, dialogue-recording, dubbing-stage, pro-tools-9, dubbing

Ok,

So I'm assisting a feature film dub and while attempting to setup the tommorow's actor's template, we experienced a DAE error, whereafter PT9 HD froze...

After a  Force-Quit, we restarted, and we got 
'Unable to find an Audio Interface attached to the first HD card. Please check power and digilink cables. Click OK to rescan'

We're running Mac Pro 2.8GHz Quad-core with HD 9 + HD Accel Card.

I've been through the DUC and everyone seems to suggest the usual: Deleting Prefs, Restarting, Using a different Interface etc.
Nothing works.....yet

Anyone? It looks like everyone wants to go home and cry now, but we're getting the first talent in at 9:30 and we're nowhere at the moment.

And the crazy thing was we were in the middle of final checks...

Anybody?

It's now 20:40 in Zürich on May 15.

contact AT kurthuman DOT com

Comment: A common error seems to be that the cable is incorrectly connected, but the session was working nearly all day..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem many years ago. I finally swapped out the Digilink cable and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the pci slot of the hd-card?